# Android - Accessing a button defined in another layout from MainActivity

Tags: android

I want to access a button defined in a separate xml layout from MainActivity and do things like onClick on the button. I used LayoutInflater as shown below in MainActivity but the onClick method doesn't detect the button being clicked. The button is defined inside a LinearLayout, which is displayed on a custom ListView by a custom Adapter. I can setup an onClick method inside a class that inflates the LinearLayout (xml file), but then how would I do things in MainActivity after detecting a button click?

Can I detect button clicks inside MainActivity? Or do I have to create communication between the LinearLayout which contains the button and MainActivity via Intent? Please tell me some of the possible ways of doing this.

MainActivity:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
 LinearLayout list_item = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
 Button deleteBtn = (Button)list_item.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
 deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "delete button clicked");

            statusList.setOnDataSelectionListener(new OnDataSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "delete button clicked inside onDataselected");

                    DeleteStatusThread thread = new MainActivity.DeleteStatusThread(id);
                    thread.start();
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: You might wanna check out this blog that I wrote: http://blog.antrromet.com/2013/07/handling-clicks-within-list-items-in.html

Comment: Are you sure that the view that you inflated is the one that is displayed in the layout ?, because i don't see it added to the layout

Comment: list_item.xml sets the layout for LinearLayout. Then I use an adapter to display the layout in the ListView defined in activity_main.xml. I'm inflating list_item because I defined the button inside it.

Comment: Antrromet, I followed your posting on the blog and did what you did. But the button click is still not handled. I can click the list no problem. It seems that something is preventing from the buttons being clicked. Possibly in the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

list_item should be added by main view, check your source code about it